# Behavior of alphas_ in LassoCV

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I am trying to reproduce the behavior of LassoCV outside the CV process and I am struggling to understand what happens. I am fixing the random seed in the cross validation so the behavior should be deterministic, as well as the alpha values (I figured that LassoCV re-orders them in descending order). But I must be missing something because I only get the same result if I only use one alpha at a time, or for the largest value of alpha, if it coincides between two runs. In code:

```
clf = LassoCV(alphas = np.logspace(-2,2,5), cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=20), max_iter = 1000000, tol = 0.005)

clf.fit(new_xb,ypb)

print('Alphas', clf.alphas_)

for i, alpha in enumerate(clf.alphas_):
    print('Score for alpha', alpha, np.mean(clf.mse_path_[i,:])) #for each alpha (row), 10 cv estimates of MSE
```

returns

```
Alphas [1.e+02 1.e+01 1.e+00 1.e-01 1.e-02]
Score for alpha 100.0 158200.48456097275
Score for alpha 10.0 158216.20827618148
Score for alpha 1.0 158231.52763707296
Score for alpha 0.1 158194.40120074182
Score for alpha 0.01 157886.51644333656
```

but if I run the same code with a different range, ie I change

```
clf = LassoCV(alphas = np.logspace(-1,1,3), cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=20), max_iter = 1000000, tol = 0.005)
```

I get

```
Alphas [10.   1.   0.1]
Score for alpha 10.0 165760.88919712842
Score for alpha 1.0 165704.1358282215
Score for alpha 0.1 161309.30244060006
```

On the other hand, if the first (largest value) is the same for two runs, the result stays the same for that value; using

```
clf = LassoCV(alphas = np.logspace(-1,1,2), cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=20), max_iter = 1000000, tol = 0.005)
```

returns

```
alphas [10.   0.1]
Score for alpha 10.0 165760.88919712842
Score for alpha 0.1 161330.76311479398
```

And if I run it with one alpha at a time, I get consistent results. So my guess is that the alphas are somehow changing inside the classifier, but I can't figure out why.